# How to persist configuration settings in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, persistent

I have a set of configuration settings (key/value) pair, which is meant for customization (through an admin panel for example) through Spring MVC. Are there any wide-accepted way of accomplishing this?

One has suggested using a one-row table to persist, but other has dismissed this as a bad design. What are my options? I am thinking that a property file should be sufficient in this case, but it is not exactly clear to me how to **map** this property file to a java object, as a model,  save and update it ...

Thanks for your help

Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where I work we often simply have a configuration table with two columns, one for key, one for value.  This seems to work well.  This is context-less, but can be put into context simply by adding another column for 'customer_id' for example, or 'site_id'.

```
class ConfigurationValue {
  String key, String value; 
  // blah, blah
}
```

Then just use the JDBC template to do reads/inserts/etc...
No magic here.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Properties` gives you a simply interface to read/write `.properties` files in Java. That might be suitable for your case, but depends largely on your application.